# Is Microsoft's KMS functionally the same as Amazon's KMS?

Tags: amazon-kms

As I understand it: Microsoft's KMS is used to temporarily enable Windows \ Office, whereas Amazon's KMS is for cryptographic key management.

- Are both KMS services fundamentally the same: if so in what sense?
- Is there some unifying explanation for model for Key Management that explains the two KMS versions?

Answer (score 2):

They are entirely different. Where Microsoft KMS provides activation service (as you noted), AWS KMS is an encryption service to securely store key materials and encrypt/decrypt data.